# What should I do if my Facebook account is taken over by another person?

Tags: facebook

My daughter's account has been taken over by an other person. It is the second time in four days, What to do?

She already asked twice for a new log in way, she logged in successfully, but the next day the account was again taken over.

Comment: Contact Facebook and tell your daughter to change her password.

Answer (score 6):

The following should work hopefully while Facebook responds to your daugther.

If you are able to sign in to the account again

1. Go to Facebook Settings and then click edit to right of the email section. There should only be one email there. Remove any secondary sets.
2. Now go right below this setting and you should see an edit link for the Password section. Change your password.
3. Go to [Security Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security) and enable Login Notifications
4. Enable Login Approvals by selecting the checkbox for

   > Require me to enter a security code each time an unrecognized computer or device tries to access my account
5. Go to Recognized Devices, remove all devices.

Additional settings, depending on where your daughter usually logs in,

- Clear all cookies
- Enable [Secure Browsing](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=browsing&t)
- Stay off insecure Wifi access points.
- Ensure someone is not free-loading on your internet. You may want to check the client list.

Answer (score 0):

What do I do if my account was completely taken over by someone, and they are using my account with their information and I can't regain access to my account.?